# Python draw with different Y axis

Tags: python, add-on

I have an addon with that you can define widgets (like panels) that are drawn into the 3d view. The are defined using gpu module, that has this coordinate system:

[image]

So the widget would be at about (800, 100), but of course the user would rather define the panel like this (upper left hand corner is origin):

[image]

I already keep the x and y in a separate Python class and I paint the panel with the gpu module like this:

```
def update(self, x, y):

    self.x_screen = x
    self.y_screen = y

    indices = ((0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3))

    # bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right
    vertices = (
                (self.x_screen, self.y_screen), 
                (self.x_screen, self.y_screen - self.height), 
                (self.x_screen + self.width, self.y_screen - self.height),
                (self.x_screen + self.width, self.y_screen))

    self.shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    self.batch_panel = batch_for_shader(self.shader, 'TRIS', {"pos" : vertices}, indices=indices)
```

Is there a nice way to convert the Y-axis so that I dont have to recalculate the Y-axis manually to define the vertices of the batch?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, it wasnt that hard, just had to change about 4 parts in the code where I get the height of the area and do a simple height - y to get the y position (same for the mouse cursor)

Comment: Please post your code in order to help future visitors, thanks.